# Applications of $C^\ast$ algebras in differential topology

Tags: differential-topology, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I was wondering if there were any useful ways $C^\ast$ algebras come into play within differential topology. I know this is a fairly broad question,so any type of input is applicable.